# Transformed DStream in pyspark gives error when pprint called on it

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, dstream

I'm exploring Spark Streaming through PySpark, and hitting an error when I try to use the `transform` function with `take`.

I can successfully use `sortBy` against the `DStream` via `transform` and `pprint` the result.

```py
author_counts_sorted_dstream = author_counts_dstream.transform\
  (lambda foo:foo\
   .sortBy(lambda x:x[0].lower())\
   .sortBy(lambda x:x[1],ascending=False))
author_counts_sorted_dstream.pprint()
```

But if I use `take` following the same pattern and try to `pprint` it:

```py
top_five = author_counts_sorted_dstream.transform\
  (lambda rdd:rdd.take(5))
top_five.pprint()
```

the job fails with

> ```
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.awaitTermination.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: An exception was raised by Python:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py", line 67, in call
>     return r._jrdd
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jrdd'
> ```

You can see the full code and output in [the notebook here](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/ce5ee9d65e4b3c276020b33ce2fed41f).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function you pass to `transform` should transform from `RDD` to `RDD`. If you use an action, like `take`, you have to convert the result back to `RDD`:

```py
sc: SparkContext = ...

author_counts_sorted_dstream.transform(
  lambda rdd: sc.parallelize(rdd.take(5))
)
```

In contrast `RDD.sortBy` used is a transformation (returns an RDD) so there is no need for further parallelization.

On a side note following function:

```py
lambda foo: foo \
    .sortBy(lambda x:x[0].lower()) \
    .sortBy(lambda x:x[1], ascending=False)
```

doesn't make much sense. Remember that Spark sort by shuffle therefore it is not stable. If you want to sort by multiple fields you should use a composite key like:

```py
lambda x: (x[0].lower(), -x[1])
```